# What is difference between "StringValueof && To String' ?

Tags: java

What is difference betwin this two:?

```
int a=20;
System.out.print(a.toString);
System.out.print(String.valueOf(a));
```

Thanks!

Comment: The second line wouldn't compile, would it?

Comment: For few reasons (1) `int` is primitive type so it doesn't have methods and fields, (2) even if you would use object representation of int -> `Integer` it have no field `toString`. If you ware trying to invoke it as method you should add `()`.

Comment: @Sajjad-HiFriend: Three reasons: 1. `a` is an `int`, and primitives don't have methods. 2. Prior to your edit just now, you had `a.ToString` (with the capital `T`), whereas the method name is `toString` (lower-case `t`). Case matters in Java. 3. You've referred to `toString` as though it were a field. It isn't, it's a method, so you'd have to call it by putting `()` after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.valueOf` can be used for conversions where as `toString` is the standard function every object either overwrites, or inherits from the `Object` class to stringify itself.

Answer (score 3):

Two differences:

1. Your example, even with `a.ToString` corrected to `a.toString()`, won't work because `a` is an `int`, not an object, and thus has no methods. You'd have to write `new Integer(a).toString()`. Whereas the `String.valueOf` call will autobox it, and so it will have a `toString`.
2. If `a` were an object reference, the difference would be that `String.valueOf(a)` will give you `"null"` if `a` is `null` (which obviously it won't be in your case, as `a` is an `int` that then gets autoboxed), whereas `a.toString()` would throw a `NullPointerException`.

   We can see that in the source code of `String.valueOf`, which is available with the JDK:

   ```
   public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
       return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
   }
   ```

So: With `String.valueOf`, primitives get autoboxed, and object references are `null`-guarded.